# Stellar Validators, Transaction fees, Inflation fees.

Tags: transactions, stellar-core, inflation, validators

I've been trying to find some answer in regards to the following questions. Hope someone can help me. Because I was able to find the only unnecessary answer in regards to my questions;

1. Why would someone become a stellar validator? If there are no monetary gains?
2. Are the 1% stellar coins + transactions fees added to the community pool?
3. If I can earn free Stellar from the pool. Why would I be interested in becoming a validator?
4. If Stellar it's a non-profit organisation, How are they paying for stuff + building? A $3 million loan can't cover that for that long.

I own some stellar and I like the concept behind it. I'm trying to understand it better before increasing my position.

Hope someone smarter then I can answer my questions

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please ask one question per post.  That way, each one can be answered and voted upon clearly..

Answer (score 1):

Q1 & Q3 are similar

better refer to [this answer](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/87/1063)

> "you should run your own node if you created some service relying over stellar network"

For instance, if you are relying on an external Horizon and once it is hacked or down, your service could be doomed. You have better control over your own Stellar node.

---

Q2

Yes, and you may find out more about inflation. [This answer](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/110/1063) may have what you're seeking.

---

Q4

Staff at non-profit organization are paid... It's just the organization not aiming for stocking up money.

---

And, mind that "Stellar" has been renamed as "Lumen/XLM" for quite some time, as disambiguation from the technology brand itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answer, there are several reasons to run a Stellar validator:

- You issue a token backed by some real-world asset, and hence need to protect yourself against double redemption requests.  In this case, you should run or designate an official validator and pledge to honor redemption requests that go through this validator.  This way as long as your own validator is never compromised, you are guaranteed never to face more redemption requests than you issued tokens.
- You are trading multiple high-value assets, and need a guarantee that your state will never diverge from multiple other token issuers.  In this case you should run a validator and put all of the issuers you care about in your quorum slice.
- You would like to have a local copy of the ledger state, or need highly reliable access to horizon and don't want to depend on another organization for it.